# How can I create new objects in a nested Realm List? The parent object should remain the same, but the list it "holds" must added to

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.

What I'm trying to make is a note taking app that stores "Users", and then stores "notes" that are linked to the users. This is the relevant code.

My Main user Model:

```
class Person: Object {

    dynamic var dateOfUpdatingNote: NSDate?
    dynamic var addIndex: Int = 0
    let notes = List<Notes>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "addIndex"
  }
 }
```

My main notes model:

```
class Notes: Object {

    dynamic var NoteText: String?
    dynamic var dateofCreation: NSDate?
    dynamic var dateofUpdate: NSDate?
    dynamic var noteImage: NSData?

}
```

I've written some code that can identify the correct user, and then update the Notes that the User stores. This is not what I'm trying to accomplish. What I want is for the User to create a new note, that is then appended to the Users List

Here's the code I'm referring to:

```
    var currentPersonIndex = 0 //Basically holds the indexPath.row of the selected User

    @IBAction func noteInputButtonDidPress(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let words = noteInputTextField.text {

        let realm = try! Realm()

        try! realm.write {

            realm.create(Person.self, value: ["addIndex": currentPersonIndex, "notes": [["noteImage": nil, "dateOfUpdate": nil, "NoteText": words, "dateOfCreation": nil]]], update: true)
        }

        noteInputTextField.text = nil
    }

}
```

This actually updates the Notes, but I simply cannot figure out how to append a brand new version of Notes into the List. Does anyone know the solution for this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got the primary key of the target `User`, you can query for it using the `realm.object(ofType:forPrimaryKey:)`. Once you have the object, you can then append new `Note` objects in a write transaction.

```
@IBAction func noteInputButtonDidPress(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let words = noteInputTextField.text {
        let realm = try! Realm()

        let person = realm.object(ofType: Person.self, forPrimaryKey: currentPersonIndex)

        let newNote = Note()
        let newNote.NoteText = words

        try! realm.write {
            person.notes.append(newNote)
        }

        noteInputTextField.text = nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Cool! I'm glad to hear that! If that's the case, can you please mark this answer as accepted? :)

Comment: You got it Tim :)

Answer (score 0):

Whats so hard? Just fetch the `Person` object that holding the `notes` you want to edit, then edit it, then do a `realm.add(personObject, update:true)`